# Spring MVC controller HTTP GET query parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc

**How do I, without annotations, create and wire a controller that will perform an action based on a query parameter?**

So maybe I've got a page with a list of items on it, and each one is a link like "edititem.htm?id=5".  When the user clicks a link I want the controller to load up "item #5" and pass it to my edit form.

I'm sorry to ask such a silly question, but for some reason I can't find any example of doing this online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a Controller that maps to edititem.htm. (Maybe a [SimpleFormController](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html))

Override one of the two showForm methods to populate the your model with the item:

```
protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors){
//get the id
int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

// get the object
Item item = dao.getItemById(id);
return  new ModelAndView(getFormView(), "item", item);
}
```

Also, see [Different views with Spring's SimpleFormController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762104/different-views-with-springs-simpleformcontroller)

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks, that's simple enough!

Comment: Deprecated in Spring 3 and removed in Spring 4. Spring frameworks obviously didn't want to support two different approaches, so ditched the FormControllers in favour of annotation-driven configuration.