# how to pass parameters from view to controller in Spring 3

Tags: java, model-view-controller, view, jstl, spring-3

This is a fragment of my view, and when the hyperlink is clicked I need to send 
two parameters named solicitudId and detailId to a method in the controller

```
<tr>
    <td>${user.loginName}</td>
    <td>${user.phone}</td>
    <td>${user.address}</td>
    <td><a href="/enable?solicitudId=${user.solicitudId}&detailId=${user.detail}">Enable</a></td>
tr>
```

//Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/enable", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String enableUser(Model model){
        try{
            //How should I get the values from the parameters solicitudId and detailId?
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  null;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/enable", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String enableUser( @RequestParam("solicitudId") int solicitudId ,   
                              @RequestParam("detailId") int detailId, Model model){
        try{
            //do whatever you want with detailId and solicitudId
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  null;
}
```

ref:
 http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s11.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a controller method that accepts the HTTP request object.  The parameters will be part of the GET request as name/value pairs.  Like this:

[Spring MVC controller HTTP GET query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787291/spring-mvc-controller-http-get-query-parameters)